# rust lifetime question, why can't I move a structure '1 layer' up, how do I set the lifetime correctly?

Tags: rust, static, lifetime, cloneable

I have a question for you, regarding my 'idx' structure and it's lifetimes... This structure is a cloneable multi threaded object.

This code works, how is it that moving 'idx' one layer up suddenly meant it didn't satify the 'static' lifetime requirement.

```
main() {
    let w = webtask::Webtask::new();
    // Wait for threads to finish
}

pub fn new() -> Self {
    let (tx, rx) = oneshot::channel();
    let mut idx = fastauth::createindex();
    idx.load_index("users.dat.idx");    
    let lookup= warp::path!("lookup" / String).map(move |name| { Webtask::do_lookup(idx.clone(),name) });
    let routes = lookup; //hello.or(lookup).or(check); 
    let (_addr, server) = warp::serve(routes).bind_with_graceful_shutdown(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030), async {
         rx.await.ok();
    });  
    let thread = tokio::task::spawn(server);
    Webtask {thread,tx}
}
```

-------- However, when I try and move 'idx' to the outer layer function I get errors..

```
main() {
        let mut idx  = fastauth::createindex();
        idx.load_index("users.dat.idx");
        let w = webtask::Webtask::new(&idx);
        // Here I plan to reuse 'idx' as it's really a global structure that will exist the entire time the program is running...
        do_something_else(&idx);
        // then wait for threads to finish...
        exit_when_done();
    }
...
    pub fn new<'inf>(idx: &'inf fastauth::Idx) -> Self {
        let (tx, rx) = oneshot::channel();
        let lookup= warp::path!("lookup" / String).map(move |name| { Webtask::do_lookup(idx.clone(),name) });   // IS CAPTURED HERE 
        let routes = lookup; //hello.or(lookup).or(check); 
        let (_addr, server) = warp::serve(routes).bind_with_graceful_shutdown(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030), async {  // IS REQUIRED TO LIVE AS LONG AS STATIC HERE. 
             rx.await.ok();
        });   
        let thread = tokio::task::spawn(server);
        // return our 'w' structure...
        Webtask {thread,tx}
    }
```

`idx` has lifetime `'inf` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement

Answer (score 3):

The important lines in the working code are:

```
let mut idx = fastauth::createindex();
let lookup= warp::path!("lookup" / String).map(
    move |name| { Webtask::do_lookup(idx.clone(),name) });
```

Here, `idx` has type `fastauth::Idx` and is *moved* inside the closure, so the compiler can guarantee that `idx` will not be destroyed before the closure.

In the non-working code:

```
pub fn new<'inf>(idx: &'inf fastauth::Idx) -> Self {
    let lookup= warp::path!("lookup" / String).map(
        move |name| { Webtask::do_lookup(idx.clone(),name) });
```

Here, `idx` has type `&fastauth::Idx` so it is only a reference. That reference is moved inside the closure, but the real `Idx` is still outside the closure (in the `main` function), so the compiler can't guarantee that it won't get destroyed before the closure.

Depending on the reason why you wanted to move `idx` up, you have several solutions:

### `new` can take `idx` by value instead of taking it by reference

```
pub fn new(idx: fastauth::Idx) -> Self {
```

but that means you won't be able to re-use `idx` in `main` after you call `new`, so not really a solution for you.

### You can use reference-counting with `Rc` or `Arc`

```
use std::sync::Arc;
main() {
    let mut idx = Arc::new (fastauth::createindex());
    idx.load_index("users.dat.idx");
    let w = webtask::Webtask::new(idx.clone());
    // Here I plan to reuse 'idx' as it's really a global structure that will exist the entire time the program is running...
    do_something_else(idx);
    // then wait for threads to finish...
    exit_when_done();
}

pub fn new(idx: Arc::<fastauth::Idx>) -> Self {
    let (tx, rx) = oneshot::channel();
    let lookup= warp::path!("lookup" / String).map(move |name| { Webtask::do_lookup(idx.clone(),name) });   // IS CAPTURED HERE 
    let routes = lookup; //hello.or(lookup).or(check); 
    let (_addr, server) = warp::serve(routes)
        .bind_with_graceful_shutdown(
            ([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030),
            async {  // IS REQUIRED TO LIVE AS LONG AS STATIC HERE. 
               rx.await.ok();
            });   
    let thread = tokio::task::spawn(server);
    // return our 'w' structure...
    Webtask {thread,tx}
}
```

[`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) and [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) allow multiple contexts to share ownership of a value, so that the value only gets destroyed when the last reference goes out of scope.

### You can use `lazy_static` to create a global immutable static value

```
use lazy_static;

lazy_static!{
    static ref IDX: fastauth::Idx = {
        let mut idx = fastauth::createindex();
        idx.load_index("users.dat.idx");
        idx
    };
}
```

See [the `lazy_static` crate](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/1.4.0/lazy_static/index.html) for details.